# Django WSGI cannot be loaded

Tags: django, apache2

I am trying to start my first django app with Apache2 (2.4.18).

Unfortunately, I got a bit stuck. This is the error code i get in my log file:

```
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.668937 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874] mod_wsgi (pid=14849): Target WSGI script '/home/nigsdtm/srv/portal/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669026 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874] mod_wsgi (pid=14849): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/nigsdtm/srv/portal/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669734 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669779 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]   File "/home/nigsdtm/srv/portal/mysite/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669783 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669789 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669792 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669809 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669812 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669817 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669820 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]     app_config.import_models()
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669824 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669827 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669832 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669834 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669839 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669843 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669848 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669852 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669857 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669861 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669866 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/polls/models.py", line 14, in <module>
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669869 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]     class Choice(models.Model):
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669873 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/polls/models.py", line 15, in Choice
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669886 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874]     question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:32.669900 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14849:tid 140433834096384] [remote 10.150.29.220:33874] TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.868251 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041] mod_wsgi (pid=15027): Target WSGI script '/home/nigsdtm/srv/portal/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.868326 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041] mod_wsgi (pid=15027): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/nigsdtm/srv/portal/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869029 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869078 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]   File "/home/nigsdtm/srv/portal/mysite/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869082 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869087 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869090 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869098 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869101 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869105 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869108 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]     app_config.import_models()
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869112 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869115 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869119 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869122 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869127 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869132 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869136 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869141 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869146 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869158 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869163 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/polls/models.py", line 14, in <module>
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869166 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]     class Choice(models.Model):
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869170 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/polls/models.py", line 15, in Choice
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869172 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041]     question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:47.869186 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380136130304] [remote 10.150.29.220:57041] TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:48.530646 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380018607872] [remote 10.150.29.220:42180] mod_wsgi (pid=15027): Target WSGI script '/home/nigsdtm/srv/portal/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:48.530748 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380018607872] [remote 10.150.29.220:42180] mod_wsgi (pid=15027): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/nigsdtm/srv/portal/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:48.530861 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380018607872] [remote 10.150.29.220:42180] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:48.530888 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380018607872] [remote 10.150.29.220:42180]   File "/home/nigsdtm/srv/portal/mysite/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:48.530891 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380018607872] [remote 10.150.29.220:42180]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:48.530897 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380018607872] [remote 10.150.29.220:42180]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:48.530897 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380018607872] [remote 10.150.29.220:42180]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:48.530899 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380018607872] [remote 10.150.29.220:42180]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:48.530904 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380018607872] [remote 10.150.29.220:42180]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:48.530907 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380018607872] [remote 10.150.29.220:42180]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:48.530911 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380018607872] [remote 10.150.29.220:42180]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 81, in populate
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:48.530914 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380018607872] [remote 10.150.29.220:42180]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Wed Mar 11 06:31:48.530927 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15027:tid 140380018607872] [remote 10.150.29.220:42180] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

This is my apache2 config file:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin alexandru.bran@nokia.com
        ServerName app.gdceur.eecloud.dynamic.nsn-net.net
        DocumentRoot /home/nigsdtm/srv

        Alias /static /home/nigsdtm/srv/portal/mysite/static
        <Directory "/home/nigsdtm/srv/portal/mysite/static">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/portal_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/portal_access.log combined

        WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-home=/home/nigsdtm/srv/portal/  python-path=/home/nigsdtm/srv/portal/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup mysite
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/nigsdtm/srv/portal/mysite/wsgi.py

        <Directory /home/nigsdtm/srv/portal/mysite>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Allow from all
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my wsgi file:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Project folder name (where manage.py is) is called 'portal'
Folder containing wsgi: 'mysite'

App works if I run server from python environment.

I am running Django 2.1.15 with Python 3.5.2

Could you please give me a hint?

Thanks,
Alexandru

Answer (score 0):

I see this line of error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

This one I recognized as a missing on_delete statement in a ForeignKey attribute.

According to Django2 [changelog](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/2.0/#features-removed-in-2-0):

```
The on_delete argument for ForeignKey and OneToOneField is now required in models and migrations. Consider squashing migrations so that you have fewer of them to update.
```

You might have developed your application on Django1 and trying to deploy it with Django2.

You should check that you installed the same dependencies on your production server than on your development machine.